# quantization (Reduction of colors of image)

Tags: c#, quantization

I am trying to quantize an image into 10 colors in C# and I have a problem in draw the quantized image, I have made the mapping table and it is correct, I have made a copy of the original image and I am changing the color of pixels based on the mapping table , I am using the below code:

```
bm = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
        Dictionary<Color, int> histo = new Dictionary<Color, int>();
        for (int x = 0; x < bm.Size.Width; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < bm.Size.Height; y++)
            {
                Color c = bm.GetPixel(x, y);
                if (histo.ContainsKey(c))
                    histo[c] = histo[c] + 1;
                else
                    histo.Add(c, 1);
            }
        var result1 = histo.OrderByDescending(a => a.Value);
                  int ind = 0;
        List<Color> mostusedcolor = new List<Color>();
        foreach (var entry in result1)
        {
            if (ind < 10)
            {
                mostusedcolor.Add(entry.Key);
                ind++;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
        Double temp_red,temp_green,temp_blue,temp;
        Dictionary<Color, Double> dist = new Dictionary<Color, double>();
        Dictionary<Color, Color> mapping = new Dictionary<Color, Color>();
        foreach (var p in result1)
        {
            dist.Clear();
            foreach (Color pp in mostusedcolor)
            {
                temp_red = Math.Pow((Convert.ToDouble(p.Key.R) - Convert.ToDouble(pp.R)), 2.0);
                temp_green = Math.Pow((Convert.ToDouble(p.Key.G) - Convert.ToDouble(pp.G)), 2.0);
                temp_blue = Math.Pow((Convert.ToDouble(p.Key.B) - Convert.ToDouble(pp.B)), 2.0);
                temp = Math.Sqrt((temp_red + temp_green + temp_blue));
                dist.Add(pp, temp);
            }
            var min = dist.OrderBy(k=>k.Value).FirstOrDefault();
            mapping.Add(p.Key, min.Key);
        }
  Bitmap copy = new Bitmap(bm);

        for (int x = 0; x < copy.Size.Width; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < copy.Size.Height; y++)
            {
                Color c = copy.GetPixel(x, y);
                Boolean flag = false;
                foreach (var entry3 in mapping)
                {
                    if (c.R == entry3.Key.R && c.G == entry3.Key.G && c.B == entry3.Key.B)
                    {
                        copy.SetPixel(x, y, entry3.Value);
                        flag = true;
                    }
                    if (flag == true)
                        break;

                }
            }
pictureBox2.Image=copy;
```

Comment: I just tried this and it worked fine. What is the problem, exactly? Is the image not being rendered? I noticed that there is no code in your post that actually renders the image, such as `e.Graphics.DrawImage(copy, new Point(0, 0))` in an OnPaint event.

Comment: the problem is with the results @BrettWolfington  when I calculate the colors of the resulted image it supposed to be 10 colors but it is not, and how can I preform the rendering?

Comment: Your previous comment cut off, but if the problem is that there are more or less colors than there should be, the problem is likely with the quantization algorithm, not the mapping code. Can you post that code and the contents of the mapping dictionary prior to entering the mapping algorithm?

Comment: I have posted the complete code above @BrettWolfington

Comment: I just tested this on a 100x100 image. It correctly reduced the number of colors from 15,273 to 10. Can you post the input image you are using?

Comment: i used The COREL Database for Content based Image Retrieval which I downloaded from this link: https://sites.google.com/site/dctresearch/Home/content-based-image-retrieval

Comment: A related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6623077/5114784

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code has two problems:

- it is terribly slow
- the quantization is not what I would expect.

Here is an original image, the result of your code and what Photoshop does when asked to reduce to 10 colors:

[image]

- **Speeding up the code** can be done in two steps:

  - Get rid of the most obnoxious time wasters
  - Turn the `GetPixel` and the `SetPixel` loops into `Lockbits` loops.

Here is a solution for step one, that speeds up the code by at least 100x:

```
Bitmap bm = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile("d:\\ImgA_VGA.png");
pictureBox1.Image = bm;

Dictionary<Color, int> histo = new Dictionary<Color, int>();
for (int x = 0; x < bm.Size.Width; x++)
    for (int y = 0; y < bm.Size.Height; y++)
    {
        Color c = bm.GetPixel(x, y);   // **1**
        if (histo.ContainsKey(c))  histo[c] = histo[c] + 1;
        else histo.Add(c, 1);
    }
var result1 = histo.OrderByDescending(a => a.Value);
int number = 10;
var mostusedcolor = result1.Select(x => x.Key).Take(number).ToList();

Double temp;
Dictionary<Color, Double> dist = new Dictionary<Color, double>();
Dictionary<Color, Color> mapping = new Dictionary<Color, Color>();
foreach (var p in result1)
{
    dist.Clear();
    foreach (Color pp in mostusedcolor)
    {
        temp = Math.Abs(p.Key.R - pp.R) + 
               Math.Abs(p.Key.R - pp.R) + 
               Math.Abs(p.Key.R - pp.R);
        dist.Add(pp, temp);
    }
    var min = dist.OrderBy(k => k.Value).FirstOrDefault();
    mapping.Add(p.Key, min.Key);
}
Bitmap copy = new Bitmap(bm);

for (int x = 0; x < copy.Size.Width; x++)
    for (int y = 0; y < copy.Size.Height; y++)
    {
        Color c = copy.GetPixel(x, y);   // **2**
        copy.SetPixel(x, y, mapping[c]);
    }
pictureBox2.Image = copy;
```

Note that there is no need to calculate the distances with the full force of Pythagoras if all we want is to order the colors. The [Manhattan distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) will do just fine.

Also note that we already have the lookup dictionary `mapping`, which contains every color in the image as its key, so we can access the values directly. (This was by far the worst waste of time..)

The test image is processed in **~1s**, so I don't even go for the `LockBits` modifications..

- But **correcting the quantization** is not so simple, I'm afraid and imo goes beyond the scope of a good SO question.

  - But let's look at what goes wrong: Looking at the result we can see it pretty much at the first glance: There is a lot of sky and all those many many blues pixels have more than 10 hues and so all colors on your top-10 list are blue.
  - So there are **no other hues left** for the whole image!
  - To work around that you best study the [common quantization  algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_quantization)..

One simplistic approach at repairing the code would be to discard/map together all colors from the most-used-list that are too close to any one of those you already have. But finding the best minimum distance would require soma data analysis..

**Update** Another very simple way to improve on the code is to mask the real colors by a few of its lower bits to map similar colors together. Picking only 10 colors will still be too few, but the improvement is quite visible, even for this test image:

```
Color cutOff(Color c, byte mask)
{  return Color.FromArgb(255, c.R & mask, c.G & mask, c.B & mask );   }
```

Insert this here (**1**) :

```
byte mask = (byte)255 << 5 & 0xff;  // values of 3-5 worked best
Color c = cutOff(bm.GetPixel(x, y), mask);
```

and here (**2**)  :

```
Color c = cutOff(copy.GetPixel(x, y), mask);
```

And we get:

[image]

Still all yellow, orange or brown hues are missing, but a nice improvement with only one extra line..

Comment: thank you very much for your assist i am very grateful for your help , but does the result have only ten colors?

Comment: According to IrfanView it has only 7 distinct colors. The Photoshop histogram shows 9 colors. Nor sure why either would be.. If you have doubts you can always run a piece of code over it.. which would btw be a good opportunity to factor out a `Dictionary<Color, in> getHistgramm(Bitmap)` function ;-)

Comment: thank you again for your answer , but i did not understand how to use the function you mentioned above?

Comment: I have marked the two lines to replace witth **1/2**. it clears some e.g. the 5 lower bits of each color channel..

Comment: you said "If you have doubts you can always run a piece of code over it.. which would btw be a good opportunity to factor out a    Dictionary<Color, in> getHistgramm(Bitmap) function"    I did not understand what you mean by gethitgramm(Bitmap) function?

Comment: creating the `histo` data makes for a nice function; if you factor it out of the code into a function of its own you can simply reuse it and test the number of colors in the result. When you write code it always pays to look out for functionality that can be written in a separate and reusable function. that make th code so much more useful and also easier to test and maintain! try it!